# Order by EXIF Date/Time

Tags: dos, rename, exif

I have a script with a for loop:

for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir /B *.jpg') do call :renameit %%F

Is there any way I can change the dir command in order to have my files ordered by the EXIF date/time field. The script is for renaming pictures, and I therefore would like to rename them taking the actual date/time of the picture into account as the sort criteria.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To use the EXIF data from the image, you will have to use a 3rd party tool such as [EXIFTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/).

Using just native batch commands only, you can just reference the Created or Last Modified Date/Time for the file.

Dir can order the files by either the Created or Last Modified date. See `dir /?`  The following will order the files based upon there creation date (oldest first).

```
dir *.jpg /B /O:D /T:C
```

You can also use this information during the loop with a `for /f` loop and without the `/b` option on `dir`.

There is also the `t` variable option where %%~tF will display the last modified time for the file in question.  There are plenty of examples around StackOverflow and on the web on how to parse the information you need.